# post XML data from Android and get back in PHP

Tags: php, android, xml, http-post

#### I am doing a php webserver that have communication with android phone. And android phone mainly collect location information and send to webserver while location is updated.

the code below is studied online and i cannot understand them well.

**I AM NOT SURE HOW TO READ THE XML FORMAT DATA IN PHP.**

most of the example use **Parser** and **SimpleXML**, but they mostly **know the xml file name**, however my code seems no naming of the xml file. And i don't know how to do.

code that connect the php webservice, generate xml file and send.

```
private String postLocation(double lat, double lng){
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<Location>");
        sb.append("<lat>");
        sb.append(lat);
        sb.append("</lat>");
        sb.append("<lng>");
        sb.append(lng);
        sb.append("</lng>");
        sb.append("</Location>");

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);  
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = 
            (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse
                    .getEntity());
            //return entity.toString();
            return strResult;
        }
    catch(exception.........){}
}
```